# O2 bank 2 sensor 1 engine side female connector wiring sequence

Tags: toyota, o2-sensor, sequoia

In replacing the O2 sensor on my 2001 Toyota Sequoia Limited, I pulled the female connector away from the wires. I bought a replacement connector (10869) with 8" pigtail but it has all black wires. I'm trying to figure out how to connect the color coded wires to the right place on the connector. Attached is a picture of the existing wires that I need to solder to the new connector wires. I've included a picture of the new connector with pigtail as well. Thanks for any assistance. [image][image]

Comment: Look at the male end and use the positions there - or look at the sensor on the other bank.

Comment: Thanks. Male end has only black, white, and blue wires so doesn't match. other sensor has similar colors except has black instead of white. I'll wire according to that and hope for the best. thanks again